# When and how should I use DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

)

I've already spent 4h+ searching the web for this, so I decided to ask the community...

What is the exact use case for angular's `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript` method?

I know, that this

- comes with security risks
- is not the best way to insert code into angular apps
- is not the only way to inject script tags
- etc.

I don't want to use it for a real implementation. I'm just providing
an Angular Pipe to my users and I want to explain to them when and how
to use each security context (e.g. `[innerHtml]="someVar | trust: 'html'"`).

I could find good examples for all except for the bypassSecurityTrust**Script** method.

**So, can anyone explain to me WHEN and HOW to use `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript`?**

```
$ ng --version

Angular CLI: 12.2.17
Node: 14.17.6
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, elements
... forms, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1202.17
@angular-devkit/build-angular      12.2.17
@angular-devkit/core               12.2.17
@angular-devkit/schematics         12.2.17
@angular/cdk                       12.2.13
@angular/cli                       12.2.17
@angular/flex-layout               12.0.0-beta.35
@angular/material                  12.2.13
@angular/material-moment-adapter   12.2.13
@schematics/angular                12.2.17
ng-packagr                         12.2.7
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.3.5
```

Cheers, Markus ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How run script as string using DomSanitzer bypassSecurityTrustScript() in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303446/how-run-script-as-string-using-domsanitzer-bypasssecuritytrustscript-in-angula)

Comment: Unfortunately not. As I said, I'm not trying to actually run any script, but I want to explain my users when and how they can use the `script` mode of my pipe, which essentially calls `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript`. Yet, I could not find ANY way how to actually use this. And yes, I did try to google it ;)
But thanks, anyway (y)